# I can't connect to internet with a BCM4312

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, internet-connection, inspiron

This is my first time with Linux (I am using Ubuntu 12.04) and i am having trouble connecting to internte.
I read some post and i did the following, if anybody knows what could be happening i will be very greatful!!!

I've enter `lspci -vvv` and the result was:

```
> 09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040
> PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)   Subsystem: Dell Device 02aa
>   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr-
> Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+     Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B-
> ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
>   Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes   Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ
> 45    Region 0: Memory at f68fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>   Region 2: I/O ports at de00 [size=256]  Capabilities: <access denied>
>   Kernel driver in use: sky2  Kernel modules: sky2
> 
> 0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g
> LP-PHY (rev 01)   Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card
>   Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr-
> Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-     Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B-
> ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
>   Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes   Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ
> 17    Region 0: Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>   Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
>   Kernel modules: ssb
```

The i'd entered `sudo lshw -class network` with the following result:

```
>   *-network               
>        description: Network controller
>        product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
>        vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
>        version: 01
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
>        configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
>        resources: irq:17 memory:f69fc000-f69fffff  

 *-network
>        description: Ethernet interface
>        product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
>        vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
>        logical name: eth0
>        version: 13
>        serial: 00:23:ae:35:91:e3
>        capacity: 100Mbit/s
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
>        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
> port=twisted pair
>        resources: irq:45 memory:f68fc000-f68fffff ioport:de00(size=256)   

*-network DISABLED
>        description: Wireless interface
>        physical id: 2
>        logical name: wlan0
>        serial: 00:24:2c:20:ce:28
>        capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.2.0-23-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes
> wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

After this i wrote `rfkill list all`

```
> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN     Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 1:
> dell-wifi: Wireless LAN   Soft blocked: yes   Hard blocked: no
```

Then `lsmod`

```
> Module                  Size  Used by rfcomm                 47604  0 
> joydev                 17693  0  bnep                   18281  2 
> parport_pc             32866  0  ppdev                  17113  0 
> bluetooth             180104  10 rfcomm,bnep lp                    
> 17799  0  parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp dell_wmi
> 12681  0  sparse_keymap          13890  1 dell_wmi dell_laptop        
> 18119  0  dcdbas                 14490  1 dell_laptop uvcvideo        
> 72627  0  videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo snd_hda_codec_idt  
> 70795  1  v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev psmouse            
> 87603  0  snd_hda_intel          33773  3  snd_hda_codec        
> 127706  2 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel snd_hwdep              13668
> 1 snd_hda_codec arc4                   12529  2  serio_raw            
> 13211  0  snd_pcm                97188  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
> snd_seq_midi           13324  0  snd_rawmidi            30748  1
> snd_seq_midi b43                   365785  0  snd_seq_midi_event    
> 14899  1 snd_seq_midi mac80211              506816  1 b43 snd_seq     
> 61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event snd_timer              29990 
> 2 snd_pcm,snd_seq snd_seq_device         14540  3
> snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq cfg80211              205544  2
> b43,mac80211 mac_hid                13253  0  bcma                  
> 26696  1 b43 snd                    78855  15
> snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
> soundcore              15091  1 snd snd_page_alloc         18529  2
> snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm sky2                   59043  0  ssb            
> 52752  1 b43 i915                  468651  3  ums_realtek           
> 18248  0  uas                    18027  0  wmi                   
> 19256  1 dell_wmi drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915 drm            
> 242038  4 i915,drm_kms_helper i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
> video                  19596  1 i915 usb_storage            49198  1
> ums_realtek
```

Then `ifconfig -a`

```
> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:ae:35:91:e3  
>           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>           Interrupt:18 
> 
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
>           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>           RX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>           RX bytes:6560 (6.5 KB)  TX bytes:6560 (6.5 KB)
> 
> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:2c:20:ce:28  
>           BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And finally `iwconfig`

```
> lo        no wireless extensions.
> 
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
>           Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
>           Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>           Power Management:on
>            eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I follow all the step stated on the "Installing STA drivers" and i still can't connect to internet. The enable wireless connection is tick but no wireless network are available. Please tell in what can i do so you can help me get online. Thank you very much for you responses.

Comment: How do you connect? Wired/wireless? Modem/router? Ethernet/usb?

Comment: I connect via wireless and yes is a dell inspiron laptop

Comment: Mathew is right, I have the same BCM4312 card on a netbook, and STA works well in 12.04.

Comment: When I had a problem to get my BCM working, I made a question similar to this. People referred me to this post: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) This is probably to biggest post around concerning all sorts of BCM models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

OP posted:

> I follow the step stated on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA%20-%20Internet%20access and I connected, actually I am writing this post from Ubuntu 12.04!!!
>
> I follow the steps stated on "b43 - No Internet access".

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ubuntu 15. My old dell inspiron would not recognize my bcm 4312 14e4 4315 rev01 wireless adapter so this is the only thing that worked but u need wired connection to install b43

First off

```
Sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Select all option check boxes available
Make sure wired connection is plugged in

```
Sudo apt-get update

Sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Next do all

```
Sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
Sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
Sudo modprobe -r wl
```

Module wl not found is possible

Next

```
Sudo modprobe b43
```

Wait a few moments and check for wireless activity now. Airplane mode was turned on when I did it. I turned off airplane and the wifi worked for the first time ever. This was ubuntu live usb setup so I needed to switch to b43 instead of reboot but it works better I think. I prefer to stick with live os anyway if I'm installing os I just stick to windows.

Comment: It applies to both questions tho